# Interpretation of Mann-Kendall statistics

Tags: p-value, trend, kendall-tau, test-for-trend

I am doing a trend analysis for vegetation dynamics using Mann-Kendall test for  trend detection and Sen's slope for computing the magnitude of the trend. There are 6 sites inside a conservation area and 6 outside. Below is is an example for one variable. I need some help with the interpretation.

1. I understand that the negative sign of the score implies a negative trend. But what about the score itself, what does that mean? How high the number should be for me to decide it's a highly positive or a negative trend?
2. What about the p value? Does it decide whether the trend is statistically significant?
3. What does the tau coefficient mean here?
4. I have such trends for 60 sites. What more can I do to compare trends inside and outside conservation areas?

Please suggest relevant literature if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

P value < 0.05 tells that there is (monotonic)trend and if $\tau$ is +ve, increasing trend, and if $\tau$ is -ve, decreasing trend.

P value >0.05, tells no monotonic trend, away from monotonic trend.